# Android Radio and Image version for HTC Developer Phone Device

Tags: android

I kinda confused about the "latest" version of the Android platform vs. APIs and SDK.

as far as I read in the Android web site the latest Android SDK is 2.2

I also have an HTC developer Phone, and when I go to the htc to update its firmware and Android Image (from page: http://developer.htc.com/adp.html); I found that the latest radio and recovery images are for Android 1.6

what does it mean? 
1. Do I have to wait until platform 2.2 is released for HTC Dev Phone? 
2. or if I have the latest 1.6 images instaled on my device it will run whatever I build using SDK 2.2

can anyone please clarify this for me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Android Dev Phone 2 runs version 1.6. The Nexus One developer phone runs version 2.2. You should build your apps against version 1.6 of the OS (or 1.5) if you want to run them on your dev phone. This means you won't have access to some of the latest features. However, about 25% of the devices on the market today are still running 1.5 or 1.6 so if you can get by with the older SDK you will run on more phones.

[Android usage statistics](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)